# What technology was used to determine the shape of the blackbody spectrum at the 19th century?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, technology, radiation

The shape of the blackbody radiation spectrum was known in the 19th century from experimental measurements, and before the theoretical discovery of Planck's law.

At those times, how did people manage to measure the intensity distribution of the blackbody spectrum in its different frequency windows? What sort of technology available at that time was being used to measure intensities of the UV, IR, and visible part of the spectrum? Thanks!

Comment: Wikipedia reviews technology used in early experiments in the [history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#History). Please refine the question if you are interested in something more specific.